# FragmentActivity into another FragmentActivity

Tags: android-fragments, android

I need some help to resolve my problem.

I want to put one FragmentActivity into another FragmentActivity, that is my MainActivity of the project. It is possible?

My idea, is that i want to put tabs with a TabHost into a LinearLayout or FrameLayout in MainActivity, so I thought about the possibility of inserting tabs that will be a FragmentActivity.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Could just Fragment work? Why do you need a FragmentActivity?

Comment: I don't need specifically  use a FragmentActivity, but with Fragment will work with a TabHost? I tried to use TabHost in Fragment but doesn't work. You know how to do?

Comment: I guess you want to implement iPhone-style navigation, am I right?